# How to update ClamAV in windows

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, clam

I am using ClamAv in my site to scan the CVs. I have ClamAv of version 0.99.1 and i want to update to 0.99.2.

I tried to download the latest version of clamAV from https://www.clamav.net/downloads, But i am not sure about,If i put this code into my live and it will not create the problem.

But i don't know about how to manually update the version and i can not take any risk because it is connected with my live site.

Is it like manually change the files which is contained in the db folder? Like

- daily.cvd
- main.cvd
- bytecode.cvd

Also i am getting warning about outdated antivirus signature database.

Answer (score 1):

> i don't know about how to manually update the version and i can not take any risk because it is connected with my live site.

If you’d like to ensure updating [ClamAv](https://github.com/tekmaven/nClam) server take no risk on production site, I recommend that you could set up another server/environment for setting up&test new version ClamAv. And if all works fine with new updates, we could create **ClamClient** object with the location of this new server, and another server could be used as a test server to test updates. Besides, as for updating live site, Azure App Service enable us to [set up staging environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing), you could set up and deploy app with updates in a staging deployment slot, and validate app changes in a staging deployment slot before swapping it with the production slot. Which could eliminate downtime.